# Is there a way to archive feeds in Google Reader?

Tags: google-reader

I have several feeds in Google Reader that I want to keep available (for searching, starred posts, etc.), but I don't want them to keep being updated with new posts. Is there a way to "archive" certain feeds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unsubscribe. The posts you've already downloaded will remain searchable.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that would work. It's not ideal, because the feed won't be available for browsing, but I can use Grant's idea for the feeds I want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

Closest I can figure is to move the feeds to a separate tag, then just ignore those. If you unsubscribe a feed, any of the feed's entries that you have starred will remain in your starred list.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I can only accept one answer, but I'll use this suggestion for some of the feeds when I want to be able to browse old posts easily.